# System.InvalidCastException Error on Specific Database Column

Tags: vb.net, oledb

So I am currently trying to read values from an access database and write them to an array of labels in VB.NET. This is for a little quiz program I am making where the previous scores they got in the 14 categories are written to the screen. The issue I am having is when writing to Label7 (column 20 in the database) I get the error 'specified cast is not valid'. I have checked my txt file and database thoroughly to see what is wrong with this specific value and I cannot see a difference. It is still written as a 32 bit integer like all the others, for which the code has no issues.

```
Dim LabelArray() As Control = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6, Label7, Label8, Label9, Label10, Label11, Label12, Label13, Label14}
    Dim x As Integer = 2
'starting at the the 3rd column in the database

    Dim QArray(13) As String 'reading names of the columns from a txt file into the array
    FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath & "\sqlscores.txt", OpenMode.Input) 'load files
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        QArray(j) = LineInput(1) 'input into array
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    FileClose(1)

    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    Dim conn1 = MyConnection2() 'connects to microsoft access database

    Dim temp As String

    For i = 0 To 13 'for each item in the array
        Dim command = New OleDbCommand("Select * From Users Where Username='" & usernames & "' and " & QArray(i) & " >= 0", conn) 'look for that column in the database where their username and score is more than 0

        Dim reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()

                temp = (reader.GetInt32(x)).ToString 'read value and convert to string

            LabelArray(i).Text = temp 'assign temp to label text

            x = x + 3 'increment by 3 as correct column is in every third column
        End While
    Next i
```

Below is a screenshot of the database (the specific column) that is causing the issue.
[The first field is the section that is playing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A1z8.png)

[As you can see, it has the same properties as a section that does work compared to a section that does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSkka.jpg)

I have tried deleting the column and adding it again, which makes no difference. I have also checked the label (and re-added it) in VB to see if that was the issue, which it was not. It appears to think that the value in that column, which is just currently the 32 bit integer "4" cannot be converted to a string. I am only interested in the practice scores in the db which can be seen in the column names.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Which line?  The one using `reader.GetInt32` or the next one?

Comment: ...and yes, you are missing a few things: SQL Parameters, disposing of the DBConnection and Command, NET File IO methods (which would make creating `QArray` 1 line of code).  And also, you havent read [Ask] or taken the [tour] as you agreed to when you signed up